# Do not show the same elements in a single array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to show the same elements in a single array

I would like to send spec tagged fields to the SOAP service in the XML file. These fields are the values ​​that specify the product properties.
I need to add these fields as specs under specs and convert them to string.

**XML file**

```
<specs>
 <spec name="Brand" value="xxx" required="true" />
 <spec name="Model" value="xxx" required="true" />
 <spec name="Status" value="xxx" required="true" />
 <spec name="box" value="xxx" required="true" />
 <spec name="Camera" value="xxx" required="false" />
</specs>
```

I wanted to convert these fields to string and get them as `spec`

i tried like this

```
$array= array( 
 'specs'=>array(
    'spec'=>array(
        'name'=>'Brand',
        'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
        'required'=>true,
    ),
    'spec'=>array(
        'name'=>'Model',
        'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
        'required'=>true,
    ),
    'spec'=>array(
        'name'=>'Status',
        'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
        'required'=>true,
    ),
    'spec'=>array(
        'name'=>'Camera',
        'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
        'required'=>true,
    )
));
print_r($array);
```

Always gets the bottom array.

I want to list all the strings found here under spec but I couldn't. How do I list all strings with the `Name` tag?

Comment: Your array has invalid structure. Also, it's hard to understand what do you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exact output you want but I think below one is solve your problem.

```
<?php
$array['specs']['spec']= array( 
     
        '0'=>array(
            'name'=>'Brand',
            'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
            'required'=>true,
        ),
        '1'=>array(
            'name'=>'Model',
            'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
            'required'=>true,
        ),
        '2'=>array(
            'name'=>'Status',
            'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
            'required'=>true,
        ),
        '3'=>array(
            'name'=>'Camera',
            'value'=>array('xxx','xxx'),
            'required'=>true,
        )
    );
    print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [specs] => Array
        (
            [spec] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Brand
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => xxx
                                    [1] => xxx
                                )

                            [required] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Model
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => xxx
                                    [1] => xxx
                                )

                            [required] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Status
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => xxx
                                    [1] => xxx
                                )

                            [required] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Camera
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => xxx
                                    [1] => xxx
                                )

                            [required] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```